# How to use a specific stylesheet for only 1 page in Play

Tags: html, css, scala, program-entry-point

I am trying to associate a stylesheet with only one page in my main.scala.html page however I am unsure of what syntax I should be using. The style I am trying to use is called "page_options_2.css" and the page I am trying to associate it with is called "signup.scala.html"

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

In the `<head>` tag of the signup.scala.html include the following:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="your_signup_scala.css">
</head>
```

Or if the style differences are not that extensive, you can include them directly in the `<head>` tag directly like so:

```
<style>
    hr {color:blue;}
    p {margin-left:20px;}
    ... etc ...
</style>
```

Comment: there is no head tag in the signup.scala.html, the header, footer, css, and javscript are all within the main.scala.html file and each other file references that. I need some sort of if statement to say if(signup.scala.html) is active, use page_options_2.css

Comment: Are you using some sort of template system? Else you really should have a head tag

Comment: yep it's a template system. I created the <head> tags like you said in the signup.html file and it included the css I wanted however it is also referencing the main.scala.html page and using that css for the header and footer as well.

Comment: Well then your question is not really very clear and you need to revise it and tell people more about what you are actually doing. As you've currently asked the question, the answer posted is the correct one.  If you are using templates of some kind, like FreeMarker, you need to tell people that in the question and give an example.